# Mysql Query for getting first instance of a element

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has data like below(sorted by date)

```
COL_A | COL_B

Item1 | Date1
Item2 | Date1
Item2 | Date2
Item1 | Date3
Item3 | Date3
```

Now I want a query that will return the first instance of every Item ie the result set should be like;

```
COL_A | COL_B

Item1 | Date1
Item2 | Date1
Item3 | Date3
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is the first instance of each and no further information then its a simple GROUP BY with MIN:

```
select Col_A, min(Col_B) MinColB
from tbl
group by Col_A
```

If you want further information from the table having found the first instance:

```
select t1.Col_A, t1.Col_B, t1.otherField...
from tbl t1
  inner join (select Col_A, min(Col_B) MinColB
              from tbl
              group by Col_A) t2 on t2.Col_A = t1.Col_A and t2.MinColB = t1.Col_B
```

You use the derived table to find the first date per Col_A and then join back to the table to retrieve further details

Answer (score 1):

This is a rudimentary group aggregate on `MIN(COL_B)`, provided `COL_B` is a proper datetime type:

```
SELECT
  COL_A,
  MIN(COL_B) AS FIRST_COL_B
FROM tbl
GROUP BY COL_A
ORDER BY COL_A ASC
```

I recommend reviewing [the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) on aggregate functions and `GROUP BY`.